# Does C language supports inheritance?

Tags: c

Suppose we have a header file "add.h" with "add(int,int)" function , "subtract.h" header file with "subtract(int,int)" function .Suppose we have a header file "calc.h" as follows-:

```
--------------add.h-------------
int add(int a,int b)
{
     return (a+b);
}

-------------sub.h--------------
int sub(int a,int b)
{
     return (a-b);
}

-------------calc.h-------------
#include "add.h"
#include "sub.h"

------------program.c-----------
#include "calc.h"
#include stdio.h
#include conio.h

void main()
{
    printf ("%d",add(1,2));
    printf ("%d",sub(3,1)); 
}
```

Can't we say that it is the form of inheritance where calc.h is inhering from add.h and sub.h and program.c is inheriting from calc.h?
I know this may be silly doubt to ask but I want to clarify my doubt?
Furthur Please tell me why should one prefer  Object Oriented Prog. rather than procedural programming?

Comment: It's not inheritance because there are no objects. You are including things into the symbol table of your program.

Comment: you are just including different  modules, that's not inheritance

Comment: You can do much better "inheritance" with C with casting `struct` pointers: `struct a { int i; }; void func_for_a(struct a *a) { a->i = 10; } struct b { struct a parent; int j; }; void func_for_b(struct b *b) { func_for_a((struct a *)b); b->j = 15; }`

Answer (score 5):

No, this is no inheritance. This is just simple inclusion. You can imitate inheritance in C with nested structs, a prominent example for this is the GTK framework. But C itself does not support inheritance.

Nobody says you should prefer OO. It's simply your choice. Many find it easier, especally in teams >2 people, to maintain OO code. But what you use is your choice.

Comment: I believe people have been writing proper OO code with vtables and dynamic dispatch in C for a long time... I don't think C++ was just invented out of thin air. C is a general-purpose language and you can do anything you like, there's just no native language support for OO.

Comment: That's what I said. You can emulate it, but there is no OO in the C language itself.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the OO or procedural question:

OO has always been surrounded by a big hype. There are a lot of things associated with OO, though if you remove the fluff and hype features, OO boils down to three major corner stones: *modular programming* with autonomous modules that lack coupling to parts of the program they don't need to know about (very important), *private encapsulation* which prevents accidental or intentional access to variables that shouldn't be altered from outside the module, to prevent bugs and spaghetti code (important) and *inheritance* with polymorphism, which can make code easier to maintain and expand in the future (somewhat useful).

Modular programming isn't related to the language at all, it is simply part of good program design. Private encapsulation is supported by C through the static keyword and through incomplete type, although it is crude compared to OO languages with support for a private keyword. Inheritance isn't supported by C, though as mentioned by others you can achieve it with various struct tricks.

Then of course OO languages also come with a lot of other things such as constructors/destructors, interfaces, generic objects, operator overloading etc etc. You don't really need these things to write programs, though some of them make programming easier.

My answer to OO vs procedural is: You should use modular program design and private encapsulation. Both happen to be regarded as good OO practice, but nothing is stopping you from using them in a procedural program and nothing is stopping you from using them in C.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not inheritance. Inheritance would mean that calc.h can modify the implementation of add() and substract(), which it can't since it only contains declarations.

Even if you decided that substract.c contains a new implementation of add(), then you'd run into a problem because the linker wouldn't know which version of the function to choose from.